Right-skewed and Mesokurtic distribution, is this possible in a dataset?
Example 1:
Kurtosis: leptokurtic
Skewness: right-skewed
Example 2:
Kurtosis: leptokurtic
Skewness: left-skewed
Example 3:
Kurtosis: platykurtic
Skewness: right-skewed
Example 4:
Kurtosis: platykurtic
Skewness: left-skewed
Example 5:
Kurtosis: mesokurtic
Skewness: right-skewed
Example 6:
Kurtosis: mesokurtic
Skewness: left-skewed
Example 7:
Kurtosis: leptokurtic
Skewness: zero-skewed
Example 8:
Kurtosis: platykurtic
Skewness: zero-skewed
Example 9:
Kurtosis: mesokurtic
Skewness: zero-skewed
Which of the above examples can be observed simultaneously on a dataset?
Skewness and kurtosis are statistical measures used to describe the shape of a data distribution. Skewness focuses on the symmetry of the distribution, while kurtosis assesses the height and tail thickness. These two measures are examined separately, and their coefficients are calculated on a dataset. There are three types of kurtosis and skewness. I have shown all possible variations in 9 examples above.
Which of these can be observed simultaneously in a dataset?
AI tools (such as Gemini, GPT) can explain that all of them are possible with examples. However, I don't think examples 3, 4, 5, and 6 can be observed simultaneously in a dataset. It doesn't make sense. For this reason, I asked AI tools to create example dataframes in Python for examples 3,4,5,6, but they failed. The coefficients of kurtosis and skewness were not consistent.
I would be very happy if you could share your thoughts on this matter and provide some inspiration for me.
Question for gpt and gemini;
Can you create a dataframe which the values have a right-skewed and mesokurtic distribution in python? Also can you show kde density and coefficient of kurtosis and skewness?
Is it possible for a numeric variable to have both a right-skewed and mesokurtic distribution simultaneously?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Generate a large sample size with a right-skewed distribution
data = np.random.gamma(shape=2, scale=3, size=10000)

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': data})

# Calculate skewness and kurtosis
skewness = df['value'].skew()
kurtosis = df['value'].kurt() # this is excess kurtosis, default(fisher=True). This value should be close to 0, not 3.

print("Skewness:", skewness)
print("Kurtosis:", kurtosis)

# Visualize the distribution
sns.kdeplot(data=df['value'])
plt.title('Kernel Density Estimation')
plt.show()

As you can see, the results of coefficient are not consistent.

All are possible. Note that in 5 and 6, mesokurtic does not imply normal, so they are possible too. For examples of 3 and 4, just play around with beta distributions.
